cc1plus going almost idle after a while
Does not matter if i pass -j3 or -j2 to make command.
Sooner or later all the cc1plus processes go from around 100% CPU usage to almost none
What is that ?



your top shows a load of 4 or more. So, something else is busy. If I'd take a guess, it's ld and everything is well :)

The process is also in uninterruptible sleep (D state) which is likely to mean it's waiting on disk access.  EDIT: So is the kswapd0 process, which is telling.

And finally, the build has completed after about a day of trials. Much longer than a few days ago (same hardware, different OS)

There's two reasons for processes top not be scheduled:

too many processes that could do work, but too few CPU time slots. Very likely, that's part of the issue here – building software isn't only running cc1plus, but also linking (ld), and often, that is a very intense process, and your compilation might be both logically blocked by that, and also drained off the chance to proceed by resource exhaustion.
They're blocked by something else. And that's very likely the case here: Note how your maxing out your swap usage? So, whatever your CPU is doing, as soon as it accesses a memory page, there's a fairly high chance it'll need to read and later write that from and to non-volatile storage. That takes several orders of magnitude longer, in which a program "can't do anything".

In your case, your device being a raspberry pi, and as it seems, one with extremely little RAM, that non-volatile memory is either an SD card (incredily slow) or USB-attached external storage (better, but not tolerable), and used all the time when you compile complex C++ software. If it is an SD card, you  probably get to replace it relatively soon – SD cards (very few exceptions) are not made for this kind of random-access heavy writing, and their internal block reserves get used up rapidly.
The problem here is that you're trying to build software for an embedded device, on the embedded device. Don't do that. Cross-compile the things you want to run on the raspberry pi on a "proper" machine, like a PC. GQRX is a Qt-heavy GNU Radio-based graphical toolkit, and it's no surprise you are giving your RPi a hard time building it.
So, cross-compilation is the magic word here. Now, GQRX is packaged for Raspberry Pi OS (which I guess you're using?), and in a relatively recent version. Unless you're working on a bugfix: maybe stick with the latest version of Raspberry Pi OS and install GQRX simply via apt instead of building it from source? You win nothing by doing the latter, if you use the version of Raspberry Pi OS meant for your Pi (e.g., not a 32 bit OS for a 64 bit computer).
If you really need to work with GQRX with modifications, set up a cross-compile environment; it shouldn't be hard, I just think the raspberry Pi foundation "forgot" to document it (claiming the Pis are fast enough for on-target compilation, which is both demonstrably wrong and useless for automated  software testing; I can't scale to 100 raspberry Pis in my closet to do builds in parallel automatedly, but I might have a build server at hand, or rent one for a couple of minutes at a time).
Alternatively: Running Raspberry Pi OS in a VM on a PC works well, and you can give that VM as much RAM as you want. It of course works even better on a machine with the same instruction set, as the compiler would run at native speeds. (If that wasn't the case, amazon would not these days be a datacenter provider with a small retail service attached to it, but the other way around.)
